# Added button as a accessory view of tabelViewCell but the action set for that is not calling

Tags: iphone

I have implemented createCellForTableview: method in AppDelegate which creates the cell add appropriate UIButton as accessoryView to the cell and returns the cell to the controller.In my viewController i am creating the instance of the accessoryView and adding the target to the button as fallows:

```
 button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
 [button setTitle:@"access" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button setTitle:@"access" forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(accessButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

My problem here is, the button action not being called.Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: change your 4th line to this `[button addTarget:self action:@selector(accessButtonTapped)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; `

Answer (score 0):

Change the @selector to accessButtonTapped:

Answer (score 0):

why you are passing the even in the selector method ..try this one..

```
button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
[button setTitle:@"access" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"access" forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(accessButtonTapped:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

may this will help you

Comment: please check are you getting the button object??

Comment: what it is @Arundhati it is UIButton Object or UIAccessoryView?

Comment: hey just put your button method what you have written ??

Comment: Its UIButton not acceossryView.I have done as in apple doc said still not working

Comment: I am using grouped tableview is this reason for the issue?

Comment: can you put your button method??are you finding any crash or what?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13162/discussion-between-arundhati-and-abhishek)

Answer (score 0):

If it is accessory button,you need to call this method :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Its not at all calling this delegate

Comment: Have you connected tableview to its delegate properly?

Comment: Yup.BreakPoint hitting inside cellForRowAtIndex